# Neo4j resolve nodes using case class from shortpath using anormcypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query as follows:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((s:DumbNode { x:1, y:1 })-[*..5000]-(f:SmartNode { description:'Thing' })) 
RETURN p
```

I'd like to be able to extract the Vertices/Edges from the path using case classes, like I can do with a regular Match.

I can see that the result p contains two tuples with the relationship and node data. But the undlerying data are not CypherResult rows but rather RESTFUL endpoints for each node or edge in the path.

Is there a proper way to do this or am I going to have to iterate over the provided data and make calls using the node and edge ids?

Comment: They changed the way paths work in 2.0 as of RC1. Let me see if I can find a good way.

Comment: I'm thinking I can do this? MATCH p = shortestPath((s:DumbNode { x:1, y:1 })-[*..5000]-(f:SmartNode { description:'sda' })) return extract(ver IN nodes(p) | ver.x as x, ver.y as y)

Comment: yeah, nodes(p) is probably the easiest way to get node data. need to build a new NeoPath type it looks like. :/ worth adding to issue backlog.

Comment: My approach doesn't work, as you can't extract two properties. I guess I'll give your below approach a try. PS You re-tweeted me last night and I was hoping you'd be the one to reply to this question.

Comment: anormcypher inquiries get starred in my inbox automatically. :P I've been doing more go than scala lately, but I need to give anormcypher some TLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I came up with, if you're looking for nodes. You can convert to a Seq of NeoNodes with the implicit converters in AnormCypher:

```
Cypher("""
  MATCH p = shortestPath((s:DumbNode { x:1, y:1 })-[*..5000]-(f:SmartNode { description:'Thing' })) 
  RETURN nodes(p)
""")().map(row => 
  row[Seq[NeoNode]]("nodes(p)")
)
```